# Problem with scraping news headlines in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

I am trying to scrape news headlines in R. Here is the sample code I have written. However, it is giving me a null set. Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(rvest)

news_url1 <- "https://www.washingtonpost.com/newssearch/?query=economy&sort=Relevance&datefilter=All%20Since%202005&startat=0#top"
news_html1 <- read_html(as.character(news_url1))
news_html1 %>% html_nodes(".pb-feed-headline")%>% html_text()
```

Comment: Note that what you see in your web browser isn't necessarily the same as what `read_html` will find. Many site change their content using javascript after the page loads and `read_html` can't execute that javascript. Maybe try a package like RSelenium to use R to control a web browser. Also some pages use different methods to prevent scraping.

Comment: Another technique (that can save a lot of frustration with selenium-based solutions that are very sensitive to *timing*) is to debug the browser window (e.g., firefox, chrome) and look at all of the other network connections. With some sites, you can find a direct URL that requires no parsing, hinting at an underlying API. (With other sites, it's just as obscure.) My point is that sometimes the javascript-loaded content is just as discoverable and able to be scraped, you just need to know which href to trace.